# PYTHON: xPath won't locate and type in a field. Using selenium, Webdriver, etc

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, python-webbrowser

I have been researching xPath with selenium for the past couple days and haven't been able to find an answer to my question. I have followed some guides on how to locate a text field using 'inspect' on a webpage and then send_keys() to that field. But I am coming up with a few errors:

```
import webbrowser
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome

driver = webdriver.Chrome
webbrowser.open("https://www.facebook.com/")

id_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="email"]')
id_box.send_keys('username')
```

It's responding with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/****/Library/Preferences/PyCharmCE2019.1/scratches/scratch_11.py", line 21, in <module>
id_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="email"]')
TypeError: find_element_by_xpath() missing 1 required positional argument: 'xpath'
```

I have tried changing my code to this:

```
id_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath='//*[@id="email"]')
```

but then it gives me this error:

```
    id_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath='//*[@id="email"]')
    TypeError: find_element_by_xpath() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

I've tried everything my small brain can think of, and everything larger brains such as google has suggested. But It will not send keys or recognize the text box. I've also tried other things as find_element_by_id, or find_element_by_name, but still have no success. I tried doing a google sign in script before this, and yielded the same results.

(P.s) the link does open with webbrowser.open("https://www.facebook.com")
but it doesn't do anything after that.

Comment: Throw the error message at a websearch. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I have tried doing websearches but haven't yielded any results concerning the problem I am having.

Comment: First thing that came to my mind is that you didn't use the `get` method of the `driver` object. https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html

Comment: Another hint: You need to provide a [mcve]. In your case, I'm sure that the `webbrowser` object is unused. The one use it has doesn't cause errors and it seems unrelated to the rest. The you just have three lines left (eliminating the duplicate one) until the error happens. Now, I haven't actually tried it, but it seems to me that `driver` is the driver class and not an instance of the driver! Your line needs to be `driver = webdriver.Chrome()`, possibly with additional parameters passed to the constructor.

Comment: My advice is to walk thru your code line by line.  You have clear errors (e.g. `webdriver.Chrome`, some variable weirdness) and duplicate code.  Just start by launching the browser...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start clean

1. Install [Chrome browser](https://www.google.com/chrome/)
2. Install matching version of the [Chromedriver](http://chromedriver.chromium.org)
3. [Install the latest version](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Selenium+With+Python) of [selenium](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/) using [pip](https://pypi.org/project/pip/)

   ```
   pip install -U selenium
   ```
4. Use [Explicit Wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) to help Selenium to locate the element

Example suggested code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome("c:\\path\\to\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://facebook.com")

id_box = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id ='email']")))
id_box.send_keys("username")
driver.quit()
```